# My React app fails to process CORS ajax request with the fetch API

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, mongodb, reactjs

I am slowly inching towards having a node/mongo backend with my react application. I am using the [Create-React-App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#integrating-with-a-node-backend) to implement a small personal app with a backend that takes information from [Formsy](https://github.com/christianalfoni/formsy-react) submit value and then posts it into a database. Here is my code so far:

`src/modules/mongo.js`

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
const ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/danielrubio';
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(3001,function() {
 console.log('listening')
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});


app.post('http://localhost:3001/contact_submissions', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(res);
})
```

Here is my `src/modules/contact.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Formsy from 'formsy-react';
import { FormsyText } from 'formsy-material-ui/lib';
import Paper from 'material-ui/Paper';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import Snackbar from 'material-ui/Snackbar';
import '../assets/css/style.css';

class ContactForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = { open: false };
  }

  handleSubmit(data) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("json", JSON.stringify(data));
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/contact_submissions', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
    })
  }

  .......more code.....
```

According to the Create react app github page. This should work. Well at least it should work to `console.log` the response. But that is not what is happening.Instead I get this error `contact.js:68 POST http://localhost:3001/contact_submissions 404 (Not Found)` I'm not sure why I get this error. I've specified my express route explicitly and even hard coded my port number onto localhost. There should be no reason why it can't be found.

My second approach (again from create-react-app) was to add the `"proxy": "http://localhost:3001"` line in package.json. Here is the error I received:

```
Fetch API cannot load http://localhost:3001/contact_submissions. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
contact:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

The create-react-app documentation says that I should not be having this error if I were to add the `proxy` line in my package.json but clearly I'm having problems. What can I be doing wrong here?

Comment: At the very least, remove hostname from your route: app.post('/contact_submissions', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(res);
})

Comment: maybe use the express cors module? https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: @DenisMysenko getting closer that worked to get me through the next step. Thanks!